# A word for two very different things juxtaposed?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a word for when, say, in an artwork, there are various items that are completely different to each other, or anachronistic? Like, for example, a watch from the 1800s and a Snoopy figurine?

Answer (score 4):

Formally, you could talk about them being an "incongruous" juxtaposition. And informally, you can say that they are "like chalk and cheese".

Answer (score 2):

For the example of the watch and Snoopy, I would say the items are *unrelated*, if I saw them, for example, on a shop shelf.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for "surrealist", which is an adjective describing anything that was incongruously juxtaposed.

["Surrealism"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/surrealism) refers to a movement which specialised in fantasy and incongruous juxtaposition.