# "Anachronism" is to "time" as what is to "space"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

Is there a noun for something that is "out of place" in space, like an anachronism is "out of place" in time? E.g., an old-timey barber shop in a chic neighborhood.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A word for two very different things juxtaposed?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28088/a-word-for-two-very-different-things-juxtaposed)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I looked up the Greek root for *place* and thought, "hey, maybe I'll coin my own: *anatopism*."  Except that it's [already been done](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatopism).

Comment: All the answers were equally good, but this one was closest to anachronism IMO.  Thanks!

Comment: @spinning_plate, ...then not all the answers were equally good.

Comment: @thomj1332 - I've been waiting 6 long years for someone to finally point this out. I can finally move on with my life - the relief is palpable. ;D

Answer (score 12):

**Incongruous**

(which also works for replacing anachronistic as well as 'not in the right location')

Comment: _Incongruity_ for the noun that was requested.

Answer (score 3):

A few options (mostly not nouns, however):

- misfit
- sticks out
- out of sync
- misplaced
- misaligned

Comment: I like "misplaced", though Mitch's answer seems correct given the vocabulary level of "anacronistic".

Comment: Or, since we are going for nouns: *misplacement*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is ***anachorism*** defined in dictionaries as:

[***anachorism***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anachorism)

> the placing of a scene, character, event, etc., where it clearly does not belong, either for special effect or as an oversight. See also *anachronism. — anachoristic, adj.*
>
> An action, event, character or scene which is out of time sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I like *unlikely* or *displaced*, or *unsuitable* if you prefer a negative connotation.

Answer (score -1):

how about a *conundrum* or a *quirk*?