# one word to express "not belong"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am afraid that when I hear it (if I hear it) I may introduce palm to forehead aggressively (an action some of you might in fact encourage me to do):

Is there one word to express "not belong"? As in:

> That book **does not belong** on that shelf. It belongs on this one with the other compilations of Manitoban poetry.

Or:

> I really feel I **don't belong** here. I mean, everyone is dressed so nicely and speaks so properly, while I in my oversized plaid shirt mumble nonsensically.

Thus, I mean an antonym to **belong** in the sense of "used to say that someone or something should be in a particular place or situation" (from M-W).

Comment: All I can come up with is the phrase "out of place".

Comment: You want a verb not an adjective, right? So something like "I unbelong here" -- well, except better :)

Comment: Someone had a bad day and voted down everything on the page. Trolls on an English language discussion board? What's next cannibalistic Buddhists?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider *amiss, incongruous,* or *mismatched*.

While all three might work in your first sentence only *incongruous* and *mismatched* really fit in your second one.

Answer (score 1):

The two example you give seem different to me. And getting that meaning in a single word is a challenge.

---

For the first example

> That book does *not belong* on that shelf.

*Out of place* could be used here, as in

> That book *is out of place* on that shelf.

Contracting the phrase to one word gives

> That book *is **misplaced*** on that shelf.

The [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/misplaced) dictionary defines *misplaced* as *1.1 Not appropriate or correct in the circumstances*

---

The second example

> I really feel I don't belong here.

could also use *out of place*, but *misplaced* would be quite an unusual thing to say.

***Alien*** could be used though:

> I really feel *alien* here.

The [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=alien) defines *alien* as *2. Belonging to, characteristic of, or constituting another and very different place, society, or person; strange.*

Answer (score 0):

I think *outlier* or *aberrant* should fit, although I think *outlier* is better.

From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/outlier, an *outlier* is:

> 1. something that lies outside the main body or group that it is a part of, as a cow far from the rest of the herd, or a distant island belonging to a cluster of islands
> 2. someone who stands apart from others of his or her group, as by differing behavior, beliefs, or religious practices

In your examples, it would be like:

> That book is an outlier on that shelf. It belongs on this one with the other compilations of Manitoban poetry.
>
> I really feel like an outlier here. I mean, everyone is dressed so nicely and speaks so properly, while I in my oversized plaid shirt mumble nonsensically.

Answer (score -1):

### Suggestions

1. Pariah
2. Outcast
3. Transplanted
4. Inappropriate
5. Unacceptable
6. Ill-fitting
7. Ill-suited

### Suffixes

As one commenter suggested, "un-" will probably be fruitful. More than one of good suggestion has started with "mis-". I think negating suffixes can yield some good words here.

### Previously suggested words with which I agree

1. Misplaced
2. Alien
3. Mismatched

Answer (score -1):

Consider *foreign*.  [*American Heritage*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=foreign) offers these two definitions (among others)

> 2. Situated in an abnormal or improper place in the body and typically introduced from outside: a foreign object in the eye.
> 3. Not natural; alien: Jealousy is foreign to her nature.

Answer (score -2):

There really ought to be a commonly understood word for this concept, and some people incorrectly think it is [*anachronism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anachronism).

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32438/anachronism-is-to-time-as-what-is-to-space) previous discussion came up with the interesting, but uncommon, analogous word [*anatopism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatopism).

Comment: Why would anyone think anachronism works here?

Comment: @Kevin Illiteracy? It does seem to be a common error.

Comment: Perhaps you hang out with different crowds than I do; I've never heard that "common" error.