# What is the word to describe the placement of two contrasting ideas next to each other?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A word for two very different things juxtaposed?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28088/a-word-for-two-very-different-things-juxtaposed)

What is the word to describe when two ideas (often contrasting) are placed next to each other to enhance the situation or idea being presented? I believe it could describe the placement of two words or ideas in a poem, or two melodies in a song, or two objects in a piece of art.

Comment: The placement of two contrasting ideas in a poem is [oxymoron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron). But it applies to words and terms, not really to other fields.

Comment: Nice question and +1

Comment: @aedia - actually I was looking for the word juxtaposition, so this can't be a duplicate.

Comment: If you were looking for *juxtaposition*, then this is not a well-formed question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add:

> [juxtaposition](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/juxtaposition)

Comment: Though N.B. the word "juxtaposition" on its own simply means "placing next to each other": if you want to describe specifically the notion of an unusual/inappropriate arrangement, it's worth adding an adjective-- as I say, "incongruous" is one option that's sometimes used.

Answer (score 3):

One such word is *counterpoint*. This is particularly used in music.

Another word, particularly used in literature, is *antithesis*.

Answer (score 3):

You could talk about an **incongruous juxtaposition** of ideas.